# Raspbian SSH (PuTTY): Server unexpectedly closed network connection (Firewall OFF)

Tags: raspbian, ssh

I just got a RPi 3 model B and installed Raspbian on it. Using built-in WiFi, I connected it to my router and was able to download and install TightVNC. I installed RealVNC on my laptop and was able to connect to it with 192.168.1.14:1 address. This means that I should be able to connect through SSH as well.

I am able to ping from laptop to RPi, and with Windows firewall OFF I can ping from RPi to the laptop.

I then installed PuTTY on my laptop and (Running as Admin) tried to connect to 192.168.1.14 (all else left default) and got an error immediately with Windows firewall ON or OFF.

I get "Network error: Software caused connection abort" with Windows firewall ON:
[image]

and "Server unexpectedly closed network connection" with Windows firewall OFF:
[image]

(I guess, for now, ignore the message that comes up when the firewall is ON)

Console Logs read (had to type it out):

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo service ssh status -l
  Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled)
  Active: active (running) since Thu 2016-12-29 21:37:51 UTC; 3h 13min ago
Main PID: 506 (sshd)
  CGroup: /system.slice/ssh.service
          |-506 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
Dec 29 21:37:52 raspberrypi sshd[506]: key_load_public: invalid format
Dec 29 21:37:52 raspberrypi sshd[506]: Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
Dec 29 21:37:52 raspberrypi sshd[506]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Dec 29 21:37:52 raspberrypi sshd[506]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Dec 29 21:37:52 raspberrypi sshd[506]: key_load_public: invalid format
Dec 29 21:37:52 raspberrypi sshd[506]: Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
Dec 29 21:37:52 raspberrypi sshd[506]: key_load_public: invalid format
Dec 29 21:37:52 raspberrypi sshd[506]: Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
Dec 29 21:37:52 raspberrypi sshd[506]: key_load_public: invalid format
Dec 29 21:37:52 raspberrypi sshd[506]: Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
```

I tried disabling SSH in 'sudo raspi-config' in "Interfacing Options" and rebooting, then re-enabling it and rebooting.

If this is a special case, would reinstalling the OS help?

Thanks!

Edit1: I just checked, I get "Server unexpectedly closed network connection" with Windows firewall ON or OFF.

Comment: You can try creating a backup of the `/etc/ssh` directory with `sudo mv /etc/ssh /etc/ssh.backup` then deleting the directory with `sudo rm /etc/ssh` and then either restart the sshd service or just reboot the RPi with `sudo shutdown -r now`.

Comment: @fvgs so you're suggesting to delete all keys and ssh-related config files to solve the issue. How would that help?

Comment: @nauro please note that it is preferable to post log excerpts and error messages as text not screenshots only. [*Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.*](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: I wouldn't advise manually deleting `/etc/ssh`.  You can clean install OpenSSH using `sudo apt-get purge openssh-server; sudo apt-get install openssh-server`.

Comment: @Ghanima The intended effect is the same as that of uninstalling and then reinstalling ssh to fix the corrupt config files. Programs like these typically create their default config files when they are found to be missing. Thus, by moving them to a backup directory, ssh would recreate its config files. To be fair, I'm not 100% certain if ssh adheres to this behavior (but that's why you create a backup first). Uninstalling and reinstalling is also fine, but not a desirable option for someone relying on ssh to connect to a headless setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## PuTTY Keys Incompatible

I see that your openssh log is complaining about a public RSA key being in the wrong format.

Please keep in mind that the keys generated by PuTTY are not compatible with the OpenSSH server (unless you export them to be compatible using PuTTYGen.)

Please see the [PuTTY website](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/wishlist/key-formats-natively.html) for details.

---

### Edit

Actually, that looks like it's complaining about the key in `/etc/ssh/`, not `~/.ssh/`.  Maybe your SSH server got corrupted somehow?  You might try reinstalling it:

`sudo apt-get purge openssh-server; sudo apt-get install openssh-server`

Comment: Yes, reinstalling ssh helped =)

Comment: @Hydraxan14 Before I reinstall, I want to make sure it can't be done via a putty? My Pi is headless.

Answer (score 0):

You did not "install Pixel (powered by Raspibian" you installed `Raspbian` which includes Pixel as Desktop Manager (for those who use GUI).

You "install(ed) TightVNC" then "installed RealVNC" `RealVNC` is included by default, but `tightvncserver` and `RealVNC` are mutually incompatible.

I assume your real question is about `ssh`

> As of the November 2016 release, Raspbian has the SSH server disabled by default. You will have to [enable](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/) it manually.

Comment: ... but from the logs `sshd` seems to be running and reporting some issues with the key files.

Comment: "I installed RealVNC on my _laptop_".  I just added to my post that I have checked my raspi-config ssh setting.

Comment: @Ghanima I didn't (couldn't) read the "logs" - microscopic red on black! I assume people will actually describe their problem.

Comment: You're right that posts should be clear without the screenshots and put the relevant logs into the post directly (see my comment to the OP). In this particular case however the resolution of the image (when clicking on them) is high enough to be readable.

Answer (score 0):

Type command

```
sudo raspi-config
```

Go to the advanced and look for SSH service, enable it and restart SSH or machine for sure.

Other way is to create empty file named ssh on your raspbian sd card in boot.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50916/discussion-on-answer-by-kuchar-raspbian-ssh-putty-server-unexpectedly-closed).